# Javascript parsing int

Tags: javascript

When I do this:

```
parseInt(39,16)
```

I get this:

```
 57
```

What does the second argument means?

I read this:

```
radix   Optional. A number (from 2 to 36) that represents the numeral system to be used
```

But what do I get with the number 16?

Comment: You can just prepend a `+` => `+'39' = 39`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument is the number system you're using - in your case "39" is hexadecimal, because you passed "16" as a second argument.

Please [refer to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

So if you want to get decimal number, use:

```
parseInt(39, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example, a radix of 10 indicates to convert from a decimal number, 8 octal, 16 hexadecimal, and so on. For radices above 10, the letters of the alphabet indicate numerals greater than 9. For example, for hexadecimal numbers (base 16), A through F are used.

[ParseInt documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)